# How to increase the number of posts in Soho blogger template

Tags: blogger, blogger-dynamic-views, google-blogger-api

Hi there I'm creating a blog in blogger, and the there is a problem in loading the posts in the main page.
I would like to appear 20 posts doesn't matter if the post is to old. It just show 3 posts per time.
Some one could help me please?
[image]
This blue squares are where I would like the posts to be

Again thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

- Navigate to Layout menu in your blogger dashboard.
- In Layout menu you will see a section called blog posts.
- Click on edit and now you will see a popup window with several settings.
- Enter the number of posts to be displayed on main page and save.

Comment: I've already done that and had no effect at all